# Including html links inside react-latex output

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, latex

I have some columns in a database that contain strings with latex and html.

For example :
`Levels of $^{13}$CN (up to N=12) (<a href='mydataurl'>Link</a>)`

I am using react-latex to render the text in a page:

```
let latex = this.props.info; // contains the string above
<Latex trust={true}>{latex}</Latex>
```

However the result is always a string where the latex formula is displayed correctly but the html code is not interpreted and is directly displayed.

I tried some config options in react-latex but I could not get it to work. Is there something else to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML code is escaped in React to prevent [Cross-site Scripting (XSS)](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) and similar attacks. In short React prevents rendering HTML as code from string variables so that someone can't tamper with those strings and input code that runs on other users' machines.

In your example, if users are the ones uploading those LaTeX files, a user can add whatever (malicious) code to that LaTeX file and it will run on the browser of the user that opens that file in via your app.

`react-latex` (if we're talking about [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-latex)) seems to only be React a wrapper for [KaTeX](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX) and uses that library for creating an HTML string and then uses the [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) property to render it. **This could be a security issue** based on what I've described above. If all the LaTeX files come from a trusted and strictly controlled source and only really trusted users (basically admin level) can add those files you're ok, but if not please have a look at more advanced [KaTeX `trust` option settings](https://katex.org/docs/options.html).

That all out of the way, I suppose the issue is that KaTeX does not support HTML code the way you've inputed it and if you only need to add that link you can just do something like:

```latex
\href{mydataurl}{Link}
```

For other KaTeX HTML rendering examples see [the KaTeX docs](https://katex.org/docs/supported.html#html).